# Returning a function

Tags: haskell

I have been tasked with this:

> Write a function `enc :: Int -> String -> String` that encrypts a string by adding some given integer to each character's Unicode value. Now, using `enc` as a locally declared function write a function `encrypt :: Int -> String -> (String , String -> String)` that accepts a `String` and an `Int` and returns a pair of an encrypted string and a function with which to decrypt the string.

I have written the function `enc`, that was fairly easy, but I cannot figure out how to return a function from `encrypt`.

So far I have

```
encrypt :: Int -> String -> (String , String -> String)
encrypt num word = (enc num word, ???)
```

I have no idea what to write in place of '???'. I've read a fair bit about curried functions but everything I've found defines a function that takes a function as a parameter and uses that function to recursively call itself. `encrypt` doesn't take a function as a parameter. How can I define an entirely new function and return it, rather than returning its value, all from within another function?

Answer (score 2):

There's the explicit lambda approach that declares a function with a parameter:

```
-- Expression is of the type String -> String
-- Similar to python  lambda mystring: enc(-num, mystring)
--         or java    (mystring) => enc(-num, mystring)

\mystring -> enc (-num) mystring
```

However, thanks to currying, you can just take `enc :: Int -> String -> String` and give it an int, which will result in a `String -> String`:

```
-- Also of the type String -> String
enc (-num)
```

Comment: Could also return `const word`, if you're feeling cheeky

Comment: Thanks for this, though I'm still not sure I understand. If I replace `???` with `enc (-num)` then try to run `encrypt 10 "hello"` it returns an error saying
`no instance for (Show (String -> String))`.
What have I messed up?

Comment: Nothing, it's working. That just means "I don't know how to represent a function on screen". Interactively in ghci you can do `let (encrypted, f) = encrypt 10 "hello"` and then show `encrypted` and `f encrypted` since those are both strings and can therefore be shown on screen

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression would be the most direct way, as others pointed out. Note that you can still simply define your own function and return it, e.g.

```
encrypt :: Int -> String -> (String , String -> String)
encrypt num word = (enc num word, myFunction)
   where
   myFunction :: String -> String
   myFunction str = .... -- here you can use num, word, str to produce the result you need
```